# Unable to fetch contacts in my react-native application from phone's contact book

Tags: plugins, react-native

I have tried

> yarn add react-native-contacts

plugin and followed all steps mentioned in this link

> https://github.com/rt2zz/react-native-contacts

but its giving error

> undefined is not an object(evaluating Contacts.getAll).

Is there anyother way to fetch contacts from phonebook?Kindly let me know.

**Thanks**

Comment: You can try some of the steps outlined in [this issue](https://github.com/rt2zz/react-native-contacts/issues/103) on the react-native-contacts repo.

Comment: I have tried the steps mentioned in the link but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **STEP-1.**  yarn add react-native-contacts --save
>
> **STEP-2.**  react-native link  react-native-contacts
>
> **STEP_3.**  Add following code manually in the files mentioned:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

Add following permissions:-

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />   
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />  
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

**MainApplication.java**

```
import com.rt2zz.reactnativecontacts.ReactNativeContacts; //import this package

protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      mCallbackManager = new CallbackManager.Factory().create();
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
      new ReactNativeContacts()  // Add this
   );
 }
```

**android/settings.gradle**

```
include ':react-native-contacts'
project(':react-native-contacts').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-contacts/android')
```

**android/app/build.gradle**
Within dependencies block add this:-

```
 compile project(':react-native-contacts')
```

**Note:-** Installation can also be done using **npm** if you are not using **yarn** 
Eg:-

1. npm install react-native-contacts
2. react-native link react-native-contacts

Answer (score 0):

There is an npm package called "react-native-contacts-wrapper" which does the job wonderfully.

You can add it in your application like this-

`import ContactsWrapper from 'react-native-contacts-wrapper';`

```
onContactSelect(){
    ContactsWrapper.getContact()
    .then((contact) => {
        this.setState({
            importingContactInfo:true,
            guest:contact.name,
            email:contact.email,
            phone:contact.phone
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("ERROR CODE: ", error.code);
        console.log("ERROR MESSAGE: ", error.message);
    });
}
```